# Table caption above, figure caption below in ConTeXt

Tags: tables, floats, captions, context

My definition looks like this:

```
\setupcaptions[location=top]
\setupcaptions[way=bysection,prefixsegments=section,headstyle=\bf]
```

And placement of tables

```
\placetable[here][tab:table-results]{Results}{
....
}
```

and figures

```
\placefigure[force][fig:topview]{Top View}{\externalfigure[img/top.png][maxwidth=\textwidth]}
```

Now my question is how to elegantly use the \setupcaptions to align table caption above the table and figure caption below the image?

I found this answer for Latex but not for Context.

Answer (score 5):

Half part intuition, half part RTFM and I am answering myself.

Definition that does the trick:

```
\setupcaptions[table][location=top]
\setupcaptions[figure][location=bottom]
\setupcaptions[way=bysection,prefixsegments=section,headstyle=\bf]
```